# What's the Flow for Stripe Elements?

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I'm switching from PayPal to Stripe so I can keep the checkout system entirely on my own sales site. While I have an intermediate understanding of PHP and API interactions, I'm so jaded from using PayPal for 3 years I can't figure out how the flow works for Stripe. Their documentation is excellent, it's more "Dictionary" like and not actual examples.

I'm looking to sell Subscription payments from my own site. You create the HTML, include the Stripe.js bit, but what's the process itself? As in, "index.php submits the checkout form, which notifies Stripe, which sends a ping back to charge.php..." etc, that sort of thing.

- Where does the customer creation go, and how does it get attached to a CC charge?
- Where does the confirmation from Stripe go?
- Where does my price checking PHP go?

I've emailed Stripe, and while they're friendly enough they more or less just told me to go online to their documentation, which I've already spent hours in and still don't get it.

I know I'm being dumb - the tutorials online all seem to focus on Stripe Checkout, which is *the popup* that I don't want, not the custom HTML form.

Thanks in advance guys. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of different ways you can set it up. Here's how we do it in our application.

When the user enters CC information, you use the `Stripe.js` API on the client to submit the CC to Stripe, and it returns a *token*. The callback removes the CC data from your form, puts the token in a hidden field in the form, and submits the form to the server.

If you want to save the customer's CC information so they don't have to re-enter it every time, you then use the `stripe-php` API to create a `\Stripe\Customer` object for this CC, sending the token as the `card` parameter. This will return a customer ID, you can save this in your user database for future reuse.

To charge the card, you create a `\Stripe\Charge` object, with this customer ID in the `customer` field. The response from this indicates that the charge was successful; if there's a problem it will throw an exception.

If you just want to do a one-time charge without saving the CC permanently, you could just go straight to creating the `\Stripe\Charge` object, and use the token as the `source` field.

If you want to allow customers to have multiple saved cards, you create the `\Stripe\Customer` object the first time, and when they add a new card you retrieve their customer object, add the new token to the `source` array, and update it. Then on future charges you can specify both the `customer` and `source` fields. In this case, the `source` field should be the card ID of one of their saved cards.

You would presumably do your own validation of the form, and calculate the price, before calling the Stripe API from the PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe do have a section with examples and sort of step by step guides for this, don't know if you found it - its separate to the API documentation and I didn't see it first time round. [https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart][1] [1]: https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart

---

For this to make sense, you will need to install their client library for PHP (or whatever you're using) and be familiar with PHP forms.

To answer your questions:

> Where does the customer creation go, and how does it get attached to a
>   CC charge?

This is done using the functions from their library, see link above.  The customer creation is sort of separate from the charge.  You will need to store the customer ID in your database to charge them later.

> Where does the confirmation from Stripe go?

This is returned in the response from the api call.

> Where does my price checking PHP go?

Not sure what you mean by this.  Presumably you work out the price to charge them first with your code, you can then just give this to stripe as an amount.

Hope this helps.